# Why these NSView subclass instances do not get initialised [Objective-C]?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nslayoutconstraint, nsview, nslayoutanchor

I am trying to understand how NSLayoutAnchor works in Objective-C by converting a simple Swift app to it. The Swift app creates an NSView subclass which sets its layer's background color to a randomly generated color (with an extension to NSColor), then creates two instances of it in AppDelegate (inside `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`), then creates the array of constraints, add the two views to the superview, activates the constraints and... that's it.
In my Objective-C version, where I have tried to convert everything, it seems that the two custom NSView subclass instances never get initialised. A step-by-step debugging shows their value to be = nil, and while the app launches, the console says:

```
-[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]
```

From that I deduced something may be wrong with the way I initialised my NSView subclass, but not even with duck-explaining I can find what may be wrong. This is the code in ColorView.m ("RandomColor.h") is the extension to get the `randomColor` method:

```
#import "ColorView.h"
#import "RandomColor.h"

@implementation ColorView

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frameRect {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frameRect];
    
    if (self) {        
        self.wantsLayer = YES;
        self.layer = [[CALayer alloc] init];
        
        self.layer.backgroundColor = [[[NSColor alloc] randomColor] CGColor];
    }
    
    NSLog(@"Color View Initialized");
    return self;
}

@end
```

Here is the extension, if you want to test it, but that doesn't seem to be the problem:

```
@implementation NSColor (RandomColor)
- (NSColor *)randomColor {
    CGFloat r = drand48();
    CGFloat g = drand48();
    CGFloat b = drand48();
    CGFloat alpha = 1.0;
    
    return [NSColor colorWithRed:r green:g blue:b alpha:alpha];
}

@end
```

In `AppDelegate.h` I declared two `ColorView` properties called `leftView` and `rightView`, while in `AppDelegate.m`:

```
@synthesize leftView;
@synthesize rightView;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    leftView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    rightView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    
    NSView *view = [self.window contentView];
    [self.window setBackgroundColor:[NSColor systemMintColor]];
    
    if (view) {
        [view addSubview:leftView];
        [view addSubview:rightView];
        
        [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
            [leftView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:[view topAnchor]],
            [leftView.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:[view leftAnchor]],
            [leftView.rightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:[view centerXAnchor]],
            [leftView.widthAnchor constraintGreaterThanOrEqualToConstant:150],
            [leftView.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:100],
            [rightView.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:[view centerXAnchor] constant:50],
            [rightView.centerYAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:[view centerYAnchor]],
            [rightView.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:100],
            [rightView.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:100]
        ]];
    }
}
```

I also looked at the archived documentation for NSView subclassing, [stored here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/SubclassingNSView/SubclassingNSView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002978-CH7-SW4), but most of it was either not compiling or not helping in a meaningful way.
Could you please tell me where I am wrong in this code, or what am I missing?
Please also correct me if the title is not appropriate for the question.
Thank you so much

Comment: Where are your `ColorView` instances being allocated and initialized? You need something like `leftView=[[ColorView alloc]initWithFrame:someRect];` for them to actually exist.

Comment: Wow ... I had forgotten `leftView = [[ColorView alloc] init];` and `rightView = [[ColorView alloc] init];` ... such a beginner mistake. Ok ... could you please add this as an answer so that I can credit you at least for the inspirational suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sample code `leftView` and `rightView` are never allocated.

Adding `leftView=[[ColorView alloc]initWithFrame:someRect];` (and similar for `rightView`) should make the code work.